# Is there a clear explanation why the ship could remain viable for years when the trip was planned for 3 weeks?

Tags: aniara

I suppose part of the explanation is that in *Aniara*, the ship is always in space but still as far as carrying supplies for years that seems inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have supplies for years, it has supplies for a few months which the crew then eke out by supplementing with edible algae. Since the journey was intended to be three weeks, presumably with a three week turnaround, this seems to be the correct amount of supplies.

> **Captain:** How soon can we increase algae production to cover our food needs?
>
> **Officer:** Immediately. It won't burden the oxygen system.
>
> **Captain:** Restaurants? How long can we last? When do we run out of supplies?
>
> **Officer:** It depends, but in two months we'll start noticing a difference.
>
> **Captain:** Including the algae?
>
> **Officer:** We can survive on it.

Everything else the ship needs for its long-term survival is already aboard. It makes its own air, has a water purification plant, carries a handy supply of spare parts and is able to power itself through a nuclear engine.

Comment: I would argue that making a ship that can last in space for years when in most plausible scenarios it need only be in space for months (if its engines died and then a rescue mission were mounted) is overkill unless there turns out to be some reason that ships often go off course for long periods in which case who would fly? The other possibility is that it is designed to not need much resupply because resupply is expensive so while journeys are short it is a craft that is meant to be self-sufficient for very long periods.

Comment: @releseabe The ship is a *luxury* ship. It is suposed to be reusable, not a thing of using once and throw away. It makes sense to have a generator of oxygen and water.

Comment: Any sea-going luxury ship is also reusable -- I did not mean they would scrap the ship -- but has to be periodically resupplied. In space an argument could be made for the ship to be made to avoid needing frequent resupply since water and food are very heavy so it is plausible that normal operation was that the ship produced/recycled essential things to save on costs.

Comment: In addition to the answers above, note the following: (1) The ship is vast. It is designed to carry large numbers of people in luxury. (2) If you maintain a sizeable cushion, let's say 50%, each voyage would consume 100% out of the X% on board. If it's supplied for a round trip (obvious), 50% would mean 300%---enough for only a round trip and a half. That's 10 weeks or a couple of months. Recall also that a crew would always remain on board and that the ship never lands. Resupply would be trivial while shuttling passengers but otherwise would not occur. The movie explains this reasonably well.

Comment: Furthermore, the ship would be designed to leak no air or water. It recycles air and water to operate in space for decades, as many as 8 voyages a year. It's not exposed to saltwater, so it doesn't need a 5-year major overhaul. The real supply need is food. Maybe the restaurants serve real meat, but if this and carbs can be replaced there is no immediate need. Performance of some systems would degrade over a decade. My only complaint is that they should have simply dangled the fuel rods 10 kilometers behind the ship (with the engines shut down) and retrieved them when the danger was past.